# What is the point of querying OpenGL extensions before attempting to load them?

Tags: opengl

For whatever reason, I'm messing around with manual OpenGL extension loading.

Every tutorial I've found recommends first querying the extension string, then parsing it into a list of extensions, and then finally loading the function pointers for supported extensions. It seems to me that this whole process could be reduced to just getting the function pointers and then checking for any `NULL`s returned by `wglGetProcAddress` or equivalent.

My question is: What purpose does the intermediate query step serve? Is it possible for a function to be unsupported but for `*GetProcAddress` to return a non-`NULL` pointer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The extension string is the correct way for a GL implementation to tell you about what extensions it supports. Querying pointers for functions which are not implied to be present by the extension string is undefined behavior, as far as the GL is concerned.

In practice, the situation might actually arise. One often has the same GL client side dll for different backends, as it is the case with mesa. The fact that the function is there does not imply that it is implemented for all backend drivers.

Comment: So let's see if I understand correctly: The function pointers are specific to an OpenGL client library. The actual behavior, however, is backed by the GL context, which is a separate entity from the client library. The purpose of the extension string is to declare which of the entry points in the client library are valid for the context.

Comment: @Michael: all of that intrernal details are highly implementation specific. The spec just guarantees that any conforming implementation has to implement all core features of the Version it is claiming to supprt plus all extensions it lists.

Answer (score 2):

> What purpose does the intermediate query step serve?

To see, which extension are actually supported by the OpenGL implementation backing the currently active context. Also not all extensions, like new texture formats or shader targets introduce new procedures (functions), but only new tokens. The only way to detect those is by looking at the extension string.

> Is it possible for a function to be unsupported but for *GetProcAddress to return a non-NULL pointer?

Yes, this is possible.